# Automatic wordwrap in Powerbuilder MLE Control

Tags: powerbuilder

I have to display text in a MLE control with automatic wordwrapping.
The text is loaded by a script, so I can not use the Auto* properties

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about your comment about Auto* settings, but when I toggle wrapping (I have a menu item exposed to the user), I set both attributes to the same value (in this order):

1. HScrollBar
2. AutoHScroll

I have a comment beside my AutoHScroll line “having AutoHScroll true breaks wrapping; only have true when there is a HScrollBar (i.e. not wrapping)”. Maybe this is the clue behind your problems with Auto* attributes.

Good luck.